# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::setForm() in F:\WebServer\htdocs\Module15\index.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Tags: php

I am using phpMailer to Auto send mail to a specific user but it's throwing me ERROR as "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::setForm() in F:\WebServer\htdocs\Module15\index.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown". Can anyone pls help me to resolve this.

Here is my code:

index.php

```
<?php  
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->HOST='smpt.gmail.com';
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure='tls'
$mail->Username='name@gmail.com';
$mail->Password='444';
$mail->setForm('name@gmail.com', 'Tariq Shaikh');
$mail->addAddress('name1@gmail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('name@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject='Notification';
$mail->Body='<h2 align=center>A new Audit Form has been Uploaded by Faculty.</h2><h3 align=center>Please check your Notification</h3>';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "ERROR! Email is not sent!";
}
else{
    echo "Email has been sent successfully";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo

It's `$mail->setFrom()` instead of `$mail->setForm()`